Listen to cursor change on mobile browser
Is it possible to observe cursor position when you have a content editable and select some part of the text or just change the cursor position?
I need this to move virtual cursor when content editable cursor change.
Is the only way to use setInterval and query the position. It's kind of ugly hack.
I'm using Android and Google Chrome/Brave with swift keyboard. But it would be nice if there is cross browser solution.

You can use the input and selectionchange events.
const editedDiv = document.getElementById('editableDiv');
const virtualCursor = document.getElementById('cursor');

editedDiv.addEventListener('input', updatePostionCursor);
editedDiv.addEventListener('select', updatePositionCursor);

function updatePositionCursor()
{
    const selectPosition = window.getSelection();

    if(selectPosition.rangeCount > 0)
    {
        const rangeCheck = selection.getRange(0);
        const relativePosition = rangeCheck.getBoundingClientRect();


        //Here we can update the position of an virtual cursor
        virtualCursor.style.left = `${rect.left}px`;
        virtualCursor.style.top = `${rect.top}px`;

    }
}


It doesn't work, changing cursor position do nothing on mobile. Tested with Brave.
